# my c++amp code just can't run in intel 4600 GPU,which there are a gt840m and a intel 4600 in my pc

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, c++-amp

the result:

[the runing result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPtcZ.png)

my code :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <amp.h>
using namespace Concurrency;
using namespace std;
std::wstring getIntelGpuPath(){
std::vector<accelerator> accelerators = accelerator::get_all();
std::wstring intelGpu;
intelGpu.clear();
for(int i = 0; i < accelerators.size(); i++){
    if (accelerators[i].device_path.find(L"VEN_8086") != std::string::npos){
        intelGpu = accelerators[i].device_path;
        std::wcout << accelerators[i].device_path << endl;
        break;
    }

}
return intelGpu;
};
static const int N = 80000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
std::wstring intelGpuPath = getIntelGpuPath();

if (intelGpuPath.size()){
    accelerator intelGpu(intelGpuPath);
    accelerator::set_default(intelGpu.device_path);
    std::wcout <<accelerator(accelerator::default_accelerator).device_path << endl;

    std::vector <float> a(N, 3.14);
    array_view<float, 1> av(N, a);
    while (1){
        parallel_for_each(
            intelGpu.default_view,
            av.extent,
            [=](index<1> idx)restrict(amp){
                av[idx] = av[idx]/2;
            }
        );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << av[i] << "\n";
    }
}
return a.exec();
```

}

I just want the

```
parallel_for_each
```

runs in 'intel hd 4600',but no matter whatever I do ,the code always runs in the gt840m .

I don't konw why.

anyone can tell me why? thx.

Comment: your integrated graphics doesn't support dx11, so it must run on you nvidia gpu that does support dx11.

Comment: What @jack said. C++AMP is built on DX11. No DX11 card, no C++AMP